# HTML Array Values Not Processed by PHP

Tags: php, html

My Html Variables are not being processed by my php script.

```
              <form method="post" action="mod3_Variables.php">
              <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">

                   <tr>
                    <td width="100">Variable One</td>
                    <td><input name="VariableArray[]" type="text" id="VariableArray[]" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('You must enter a variable')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" title="Only letters are allowed here"></td>
                 </tr>
                                     <tr>
                    <td width="100">Variable Two</td>
                    <td><input name="VariableArray[]" type="text" id="VariableArray[]" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('You must enter a variable')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" title="Only letters are allowed here"></td>
                 </tr>
                                     <tr>
                    <td width="100">Variable Three</td>            
                    <td><input name="VariableArray[]" type="text" id="VariableArray[]" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('You must enter a variable')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" title="Only letters are allowed here"></td>                     
                 </tr>      
                 <tr>
                    <td width="100"> </td>
                    <td>
                       <input name="find" type="submit" id="add" value="Insert New Record">
                    </td>
                 </tr>

              </table>
           </form>
```

Here is the PHP that keeps returning my else statement.

```
<?php 

$VariableArray= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'VariableArray', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 




$sql= "INSERT INTO employees (VariableArray)
                    VALUES ('$VariableArray')";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


$sql = "SELECT * from employees WHERE VariableArray = $VariableArray LIMIT 1"; 

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


if ($result) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<b> These Are Your Variables in Alphabetical Order:</b><br>";
            echo "<b>Variables: " . $row["VariableArray"].  "</b><br>";

}
} else {
echo "Sorry there are no matches! Please check your entry and try again.";
}
```

It is the else statement above that I keep receiving, I am not getting the actual array form value.

```
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

If anyone knows why the information is not being processed I would truly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are pretty close. a few things.

```
id="VariableArray[]"
```

All need to be unique. Element IDs cannot have the same reference.

```
id="var1"
id="var2"
id="var3"
```

Will suffice in this case or whatever you like they just can't be the same and should be unique over the whole page. Also on your 3rd input you have an extra double quote

```
 onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')""
```

It should be:

```
 onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"
```

Lastly the sql you are using is very open to attacks, mainly sql injection even after filtering. Look into PDO or mysqli prepared statements to help combat that as well. You are also trying to store an array into your database which isn't possible in its current form.

> $VariableArray

Assuming the column 'VariableArray' in your DB takes strings you will need to convert this into a string, easiest way is to use implode.

```
$var_string = implode(',', $VariableArray);
```

and then store $var_string in your 'VariableArray' column. When you retrieve it from your DB you can just explode to put it back into an array

```
$VariableArray = explode(',', $var_string);
```

EDIT: This is how I would do the prepared statements if I wasn't using functions. It should work but haven't been able to test it. It also sorts your array alphabetically.

```
<?php 
$vars = $_POST['VariableArray'];
asort($vars);
$str_var = implode(',', $vars);
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error MySQLi: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno. ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `employees` (`VariableArray`) VALUES (?)";
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
     $stmt->bind_param("s", $str_var);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            // call select
            $stmt->close();
            $sql = "SELECT `VariableArray` FROM `employees` WHERE `VariableArray` = ? LIMIT 1";
            if($stmt = $this->DAL->mysqli->prepare($sql)){
              $stmt->bind_param('s', $str_var);
                    if($stmt->execute()){
                        $stmt->bind_result($variable_string);
                        $stmt->store_result();
                           if ($stmt->fetch()) {
                                echo "<b> These Are Your Variables in Alphabetical Order:</b><br>";
                                echo "<b>Variables: " . htmlspecialchars($variable_string).  "</b><br>";
                                $stmt->close();
                           }else{
                                echo 'Failed to find ' . htmlspecialchars($str_var);
                           }
                    }else{
                         // testing only would echo a generic message if it was displayed to users
                        echo 'Failed to execute select query | ' . $mysqli->error;
                    }
            }else{
                // testing only would echo a generic message if it was displayed to users
                echo 'SQL Statement select failed | ' . $mysqli->error;
            }
        }else{
            // testing only would echo a generic message if it was displayed to users
            echo 'Failed to execute insert query | ' . $mysqli->error;
        }
    }else{
         // testing only would echo a generic message if it was displayed to users
         echo 'SQL Statement insert failed | '.$mysqli->error;
    }    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is one way to get $_POST variable, and as I read there is no filter for explode array as you want.
You can do something like that and change this code

```
$VariableArray= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'VariableArray', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

to this

```
$VariableArray= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'VariableArray', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY); 
$string = '';
foreach($VariableArray as $v)
    $string .= "$v,";
$VariableArray = substr($string, 0, -1);
```

It will return you the values with commas that strip between them

The full code:

```
if (isset($_POST['find'])) {
    $VariableArray= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'VariableArray', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY); 
    $string = '';
    foreach($VariableArray as $v)
        $string .= "$v,";
    $VariableArray = substr($string, 0, -1);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `employees` (VariableArray) VALUES ('$VariableArray')";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($query) {
        $sql = "SELECT * from `employees` WHERE VariableArray  = '$VariableArray' LIMIT 1"; 
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<b> These Are Your Variables in Alphabetical Order:</b><br>";
            echo "<b>Variables:<br />";
            $row["VariableArray"] = explode(',', $row["VariableArray"]);
            sort($row["VariableArray"]);
            foreach ($row["VariableArray"] as $k => $v)
                echo $k.' => '.$v.'<br />';
            echo "</b><br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry there are no matches! Please check your entry and try again.";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Okay, so do I mix  Second2None's answer with yours? Please edit full answer.

Comment: Your solution did not work. It just gets the else statement to run.

Comment: @CodingTime you should change your code as well, anyway I edited my answer.

Comment: @Almong Hey almong, I don't know what you mean by me changing my code. anyway, I tried the code and it runs the else message without inserting into the database or showing me the results. I do appreciate your help, but it did not work.

Comment: @CodingTime try to use var_dump on the first $sql variable to see which string it is trying to execute and try it manually. then we can understand what is going wrong.

Comment: I added var_dump($sql); right under the first SQL statement and now the page will not load, it just says error.

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in my syntax. I was able to run it now and this is the output: string(63) "INSERT INTO employees (VariableArray) VALUES ('green,red,blue')" Sorry there are no matches! Please check your entry and try again.

Comment: @CodingTime I edited the code and it works for me, try it now.

Comment: I got the else statement to run again. I have the column VariableArray in the employees table as well. So I don't think it is a database issue. Very weird. It did not work.

Comment: @CodingTime just to be sure, you make a connection on $con ?

Comment: Yes, it just ran the else statement again. Also, if it was not connecting I would get that error.

Comment: Okay, I have another column in this table called managementid, and I am being told that that field does not have a default value.

Comment: Okay, I got it to insert after rearranging my database, but the information did not show up on the php page as being inserted.

Comment: We merge the variables to string as you want, but if you want to read them one by one you should split them by the way we merge them.
I edited my answer for your next question and here is the result for an example http://prntscr.com/j6pxk1

Comment: Well, I thank you for all your help. It still does not show the output echo on the next screen, but it is inserting into the database.

Comment: One last thing, would you happen to know how to add sort to this, so that the strings are sorted in order?

Comment: @CodeTime i add sort function to code, now it works as you wanted?

Comment: Hey Almong, the sort or the SQL select staement and the row['VariableArray'] is not running. Is there any way to add the SQL select statement and the sort outside the if statement??

Answer (score 0):

[filter_input](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_input.asp) gets an external variable and filters it but I believe what you're looking for is [filter_var_array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_var_array.asp) which gets multiple variables and filters them.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filter.asp

This is how I got it to work:

```
// Check if variable array has been POSTed
if (isset($_POST['VariableArray'])) {  
  $post = $_POST['VariableArray'];
  $VariableArray= filter_var_array($post, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

foreach ($VariableArray as $value) {
    // Insert into SQL individually
}
```

Comment: Where you say Insert into SQL individually, do you mean for me to place this : $sql= "INSERT INTO employees (VariableArray)
      VALUES ('$VariableArray')";

Comment: Can you please tell me what you meant by foreach ($VariableArray as $value) {
    // Insert into SQL individually
} ? I am having a hard time with this script, and if you have been able to get it working then I would really appreciate your help.